# optional inputs using discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a poll function on my discord.py bot that takes these parameters:

`async def poll(self, ctx, option1, option2, duration=60, channel=None):`

I want a user to be able to enter a channel without a duration or enter a duration without a channel.

I know that with basic python you would use `poll(channel=some_channel)` but with the user entering the command in discord, Im not sure if this is possible.

Is this possible to do using discord.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal pythonic way should do it,

```py
async def poll(self, ctx, option1, option2, duration: int=60, channel: discord.TextChannel=None):
    # ...
```

This way if you don't pass the duration you also won't be able to pass the channel argument, to fix that you can use the typing module:

```py
from typing import Optional
```

```py
async def poll(self, ctx, option1, option2, duration: Optional[int]=60, channel: Optional[discord.TextChannel]=None):
    # ...
```

*Note: The typehints are important, also if you pass the **ID** of the channel without the duration `discord.py` will represent that as the **`duration`** argument instead of `channel`*